# Why does the texstudio compiler output this error

Tags: errors, texstudio

My textstudio always outputs an error after executing the compile command:

[image]

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "1000".tex
```

Texstudio settings are as follows:

[image]

Comment: that isn't an error it is just the command, what was the actual error message, did the command run, is a pdf generated?

Comment: Yes ,thanks a lot.I solved the problem by clicking the Yellow recovery button on the far right.